# PCI device (64bits) configuration Memory access

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver, pci

I am using a 64 bit FPGA connected by PCI. I am using the next function:

```
unsigned long pci_resource_[start|len|end|flags](struct pci_dev *pdev, int bar);
```

However, I don´t get the right result because these function are for 32bit PCI devices.

Are there others functions which work with 64 bits? You can see the information that I got from lspci

```
0002:01:00.0 Memory controller: Xilinx Corporation Device 7022
    Subsystem: Xilinx Corporation Device 0007
    Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0
    Memory at <ignored> (64-bit, prefetchable)
    Memory at c40000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]
    Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [48] MSI: Enable- Count=1/8 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [60] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [100] Device Serial Number 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which Linux version you are talking about. But in the current Linux tree (4.5), pci_resource_start is defined as:

```
#define pci_resource_start(dev, bar)    ((dev)->resource[(bar)].start)
```

and the embedding structure is

```
/* Linux/include/linux/pci.h */
struct resource resource[DEVICE_COUNT_RESOURCE]; /* I/O and memory regions + expansion ROMs */

/* Linux/include/linux/ioport.h */
struct resource {
    resource_size_t start;
    resource_size_t end;
    const char *name;
    unsigned long flags;
    struct resource *parent, *sibling, *child;
};

/* Linux/include/linux/types.h */
typedef phys_addr_t resource_size_t;

/* Linux/include/linux/types.h */
#ifdef CONFIG_PHYS_ADDR_T_64BIT
typedef u64 phys_addr_t;
#else
typedef u32 phys_addr_t;
#endif
```

So if you are on a 64bit system and Linux is compiled with CONFIG_PHYS_ADDR_T_64BIT then you are good.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer. I am using kernel version 3.16. What happend if I have the next two PCI devices; one with 32 bit memory and another with 64:

        Memory at c20100000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=1M]
        Memory at c40000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=64K]

Comment: @manolotunez I don't have experience with 32 bit devices.  Actually I am surprised to see 32bit resource mapped beyond 4GB.